# How can I let notification display longer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I am trying to display notifications but they disappear quickly.
I want to make it stay displaying until a user click close x icon.

I tried

```
let _notify = new Notification(title, options);
        setTimeout(function(){
            _notify.close();
        }, 3000000);
```

but this code does not affect at all. The notification disappear in 10 seconds.

Is there any way to set time or set not to close ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `options` object that the `Notification`-constructor takes, you can specify `requireInteraction` which by default is `false`.

So something like:

```
new Notification(title, {
  requireInteraction: true,
  // other options
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/Notification